Mounting an outdoor box, but there's an existing recessed box
How would I mount this? I want to install an external box so I can run conduit, and we had an outlet here that was covered.



There might be a face plate for the box in the wall to add the new box on.  I am assuming you want to run conduit on the outside of the wall.  Another idea is changing the boxes, and maybe find a faceplate for the new box that accepts conduit.  Once the wire is outside(in conduit) it needs to be wet rated type.

Thanks @crip659 - the box doesn't look like it has anything to screw into at all! do you have any examples of the face plates you’re talking about?

This looks like a switch box. Can you measure length and height of the metal box itself (i.e., not counting the mounting ears, etc.)? Normally a device yoke would screw into the holes that are in the tabs extending left and right from the center of the box (but more typically mounting 90 degrees relative to this setup and then top/bottom instead of left/right) and then the faceplate mounts to the device. But with exact sizing we can figure out a solution.

I’m confused. Why are you not just removing the old jbox and running the wire (with a strain relief) into your new surface mount jbox? (Maybe you want a new jbox with ears, but the one you have often comes with little oblong washers that impersonate ears.)

Those boxes typically come with little mounting lugs (basically little metal straps with 2-3 holes) that you fasten with machine screws into holes that are tapped into the back of the box.  You use one of the remaining holes in the lug to mount it to the surface.  Here's a video showing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=PQcVPNdo8RU
You would just need to remove the existing switch box.  You may want to use a rubber seal on the back of the metal box.
